# SQL Server agent job failure handling

Tags: error-handling, ssis, sql-server-2016, jobs, job-scheduling

My team relies heavily on SSIS to manage the upkeep of our large datamart. We have over 1000 jobs, and 4000 packages. Managing failing jobs and packages is a never-ending task.

We're currently using SSIS package "error-handling" flows. However, I was wondering if there were existing tools or features (or strategies) for handling foreseeable job failures?

Most job failures are due to an exogenous problem (such as a source database not being available) - however, our solution to these problems is often "take no action - rerun job on next day". How can we code ourselves out of doing this manually (for at least a large percentage of these problems, if not all of them?

Comment: Hi @colinmac, how do you define "foreseeable job failures"?

Comment: @Arthur,  In my experience, errors follow the 80/20 principle: 80% of error events, are the result of 20% of error types.  So, for that 20% of error types, I'd like to code my solution to the failed job so that I don't have to manually act.  In this hypothetical - it would reduce the workload by 80%.

Comment: Hi @colinmac the feature I personally like in SSIS is the ability to automatically recover called Checkpoint. See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-tools/implementing-checkpoints-in-an-ssis-package/ for more info